# Getting Content from other HTML Div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two pages, index.html and content.html, where I would like to retrieve the content inside of an `<a href>` as follows:

```
<h3 class="content">
  <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>
</a>
```

I wish to get this in my index.html file

```
<body>
  <a class="mainpart"> ! INSERT HERE ! </a>
</body>
```

Is there any way to do this without `XMLHttpRequest`? Note that these are on two separate pages so two different URLs

Comment: `Is there any way to do this without XMLHttpRequest?` Not on the client side, no. Also note that having an `<a><h3><a>foo</a></h3></a>` structure would be invalid HTML

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I was just reading the HTML off the inspect element console. Would there not be a way with jQuery/Ajax?

Comment: Sure, but that's still using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Hm alright, so how can I go around using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: On the client, you can't. The alternative would be to inject the content on the server side using includes.

Comment: why not `iframe`?  you can allow only the secure links with `X-Frame-Options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the entire HTML file if that helps...

JS...

```
const test = () => {
  document.getElementById('addHere').innerHTML = `<object id='test' type="text/html" data="context.html" ></object>`
}
```

HTML...

Index...

```
<body>
  <button onclick="test()">here</button>
  <div id='addHere'></div>
</body>
```

Context...

```
<h3 class="content">
  <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>
</a>
```

However this won't allow you to select specific elements from context.html